# find all elements $f ∈ S_5$ of order 2 such that $f(1)=2$

Tags: group-theory

Let $S_5$ denote the group of bijections of the {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} under composition. Find all the elements $f ∈ S_5$ of order two such that $f(1) = 2$

I know for order of 2 we need that $f^2$ sends all elements back to themselves so $f(f(1))=1, f(f(2))=2....$

and since we know $f(1)=2$ then $f(f(1))$ becomes $f(2)$ which must equal 1

so we have $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=1$ and I could do the same for $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ but since there is an odd number of elements I am left with an odd one out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are forgetting that a permutation can fix one or more elements and still have order 2. In your example, as you say, the permutation must swap 1 and 2. So it must either (a) fix each of 3, 4 and 5 or (b) swap 2 of them and fix the other. Now you can count all the possibilities.

Comment: If you include the identity element the sequence is https://oeis.org/A000085 ... so just subtract $1$ from these values. For $n=5$ the answer is $\color{red}{25}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of $S_5$ of order $2$ such that $f(1)=2$ are the following maps

(elements not indicated are fixed):

$1\mapsto2, 2\mapsto1\tag1$

$1\mapsto2, 2\mapsto1, 3\mapsto4, 4\mapsto3\tag2$

$1\mapsto2, 2\mapsto1, 3\mapsto5, 5\mapsto4\tag3$

$1\mapsto2, 2\mapsto1, 4\mapsto5, 5\mapsto4\tag4$